# Are there any tools for guard analysis?

Tags: haskell, logic

I'm a Haskell noob and while reading about Implications in Haskell Road I came to following puzzle.

```
verdict :: Bool -> Bool -> (Bool, String)
verdict p q | not result  = (False, "LIAR")
            | result && p = (True,  "telling the truth")
            | result      = (True,  "innocent unless proven guilty")
            | otherwise   = (False, "we shouldn't get here")
  where result = (not p) || q
-- map (\x -> verdict (fst x == 1) (snd x == 1)) [(1,1),(1,0),(0,1),(0,0)]
```

Is there a tool that would warn me about the otherwise or other similar logical errors?

Comment: Note that your `otherwise` clause is truly unreachable: between `not result` and `result` all possibilities are covered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I would write this function a different way:

```
-- not result
verdict True  False = (False, "LIAR")
-- result && p
verdict True  True  = (True , "telling the truth")
-- result
verdict False _     = (True , "innocent unless proven guilty")
verdict _     True  = (True , "innocent unless proven guilty")
-- otherwise
verdict _     _     = (False, "we shouldn't get here")
```

Then not only is it obvious to humans which clauses can be left out (the last two), but also to the machine; `ghc` says this at its default warning level:

```
test.hs:2:5: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are overlapped
    In an equation for ‘verdict’:
        verdict _ True = ...
        verdict _ _ = ...
```

Checking guard overlap in general is of course undecidable; and furthermore I don't know of a tool that will try to give an approximate answer.

Comment: aha!!! I thought, I got stuck for two days on the Implication problem. But in the end it ended up to be very enlightening.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a clearer expression of your intent:

```
implies :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
p `implies` q = not p || q -- The backticks allow infix usage.

-- The assumption is that p `implies` q is a known fact.
verdict :: Bool -> Bool -> (Bool, String)
verdict p q = (result, remark)
    where
    result = p `implies` q
    remark
        | not result = "LIAR"
        | p = "telling the truth"
        | otherwise = "innocent until proven guilty"
```

Guards are syntax sugar for pattern matches on `Bool` values. For general tips on arranging pattern matches, see Daniel Wagner's answer.

Comment: `implies` would be much nicer in infix/operator form.

Comment: @ErikAllik It would, but I wanted to avoid syntax variant overload. On second though, however, I guess it won't hurt to adopt your suggestion.